# Spliting the HBase table after presplliting it

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase 0.94.6 cluster, I have a table with 100 regions(Pre splited), now can I further split the table? Can I split the table with 1000 regions manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HBase "split" command to do force split on your table. But, Looks like there is no way to specify the number of regions to split into.

Below is the info from HBase:

```
split   Split entire table or pass a region to split individual region. With the
second parameter, you can specify an explicit split key for the region.
Examples:
split ‘tableName’
split ‘regionName’ # format: ‘tableName,startKey,id’
split ‘tableName’, ‘splitKey’
split ‘regionName’, ‘splitKey’
```